# Why some cells can not be sorted in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting, spreadsheet

I am met with very strange things with spreadsheets in Excel now. Some cells with a date like `2023-10-22` can not be sorted with other cells in the same format in a column. I changed the format of the cells to `General` or `Text`, but neither works. The strangest thing is, when I copied other cells that can be sorted to the cells not sorted, if I do not modify the cell date, then it works. But if I modify the cell date, then it can not be sorted.

I have checked the content of the cell by copying and pasting it by value, which showed `45221`. It seems that the value of the cell is not correct. The sample of the spreadsheet can be accessed [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlRd0Qb77Om9bAn0KprNlCzxMWQ?e=q3Mtlj).

Cells with digits like `45221` can not be sorted. If I enter dates like `2023-10-22` manually in column B, it still can not be sorted and the paste-by-value shows `45221`. The display of column B is set to `General`.

After changing fx in cells of column B to the format like `="2023-06-03"`, paste-by-value shows the correct date format and can be sorted.

Comment: That is odd. It should show `44858` which is the number of days since `1/1/1900`. In any event, you may have a mix of "real dates" and text strings that are not real dates to explain your issue. If you want more assistance, you will need to provide sufficient data so that your problem can be reproduced.

Comment: It should be `2023-10-22`. The strangest thing is that even if I deleted the cell and recreated a new one, it is still the same. The spreadsheet is generated by c# program. I think that causes the problem.

Comment: As I wrote, you have not supplied sufficient information to give further advice.

Comment: What other info do you mean?

Comment: For a start, what does your worksheet look like? How did the data get into the cells? How does the data appear in the cell, and also in the formula bar? What does your sheet look like if you format the column of dates as `General`? Do they all look the same or are some numbers and others look like dates? What are your windows regional settings? Are you using a Mac or a PC? Screenshots may be useful.

Comment: That answers three, but not all of the questions. And I cannot reproduce your results. If I enter your formula `"="2023-09-20""` in some cell, the cell shows exactly the same, with the quotation marks. Your sorting must be strange.

Comment: If you want to share a spreadsheet, upload your workbook on some site (eg OneDrive; Dropbox; etc) and post a link here. Be sure to remove any sensitive information. And also answer the questions I posed that would not be evident from your workbook.

Comment: The sample sheet can be accessed at OneDrive (see updated post).

Comment: As I wrote in my first comment, *(in Column C)* you have a mix of "real dates" and text strings that are not real dates to explain your issue. The first 44 rows contain text strings, and the rest contain "real dates". I suggest you convert them all to real dates. Or, **preferably**, alter your data input method to ensure they are entered as real dates and not text strings. Do an internet search for detailed information as to how dates are stored (and parsed) in Excel for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Dates are stored as numbers. The number tells how many days has passed from a specific "base date"*[1]*, the decimal portion of the number specifies the time inside a day.

If a cell in a list or range does not change as you sort the list/range; the cell is likely to contain a dynamic formula that causes the same result regardless of the sorting, i.e. it has it's main references reaching outside of the sorted list/range.

*[1] Enter a zero in a cell, and tell Excel that it is a date by use of "Format cell" [CTRL+1] and you will see the base date. This date may differ depending on legacy and settings.*

Answer (score 0):

I am still confused about this. It seems having a problem of entering a string format as `Date` in an Excel cell. But I find an alternative by entering a date as `="2023-10-22"`, which can be sorted correctly.